# How to insert identity column in SQL Server with null values like in MySQL

Tags: sql-server, insert, identity

How to insert identity column in SQL Server with null values like in MySQL?

In MySQL we can place null and insert values for auto incremented columns. How to do this in SQL Server?

Example:

In MySql :

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `phone` VARCHAR(45),
  `salary` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

In the above table id is auto inc which means identity in SQL Server, to insert values into the above table MySQL supports the below query

```
INSERT INTO `employee` (`id`,`name`,`phone`,`salary`) 
VALUES (null,'Harry','9985099850',60000);
```

MySQL automatically insert auto inc id to the identity column, but how to do this is SQL Server?

Please guide me how to do this in SQL Server. I am struggling here from days to solve this in my application using JDBC.

Comment: You cannot do this in SQL Server - if you have an `IDENTITY` column, the normal use case is to let SQL Server assign a value automatically but just not specifying that column in your `INSERT`  column list; a new value will be assigned automatically by SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
id INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
phone VARCHAR(45),
salary FLOAT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
);
```

When you insert into this table, omit 'id' from the insert/select list, SQL Server will handle it for you.

Ex:

```
INSERT INTO employee (name,phone,salary) 
VALUES ('Harry','9985099850',60000);
```

Comment: That's the way to use the `IDENTITY` column in SQL Server - but it does **NOT** insert a `NULL` into `id` - instead, SQL Server will determine a value for `id` automatically and insert it

Comment: yes, we can do this. But I am writing a generalized crud application which needs to support mysql and ms sql-server DB's. Please guide us a way to do this by passing null.

Comment: If the column is an `IDENTITY`, unfortunately you can't insert a NULL in SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks, I will use ResultSetMetaData and get identity column and  I will remove identity from insert query and continue my works. Thanks for comments and answers.

Comment: I am seeing this problem with my application and want to clarify.  I am using a tool that has insert statements (via Hibernate) like INSERT into MyTable (id, ... ) VALUE (null, ...). For MySQLt the null gets transformed into an autoincrement; for SQL Server an exception.  I don't want to edit the tags in the millions of lines fo code, but rather edit the Hibernate configuration file to make this work